# Move shapes drawen in context+iphone

Tags: iphone

I have drawn shapes, such as circles, rectangles, and triangle in context..
Now i want to move, rotate and scale that drawn shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're doing your drawing, but it looks like you need to start from the beginning. If you've drawn something in a UIView using 'drawPath', you can animate the view with methods like `animateWithDuration: animations: completion:`. Here's an example that will move a view up the screen and then remove it from the view.

```
    CGRect endFrame = myView.frame;  // get the original frame
    endFrame.origin.y += 200;   // move y-origin of the frame by 200.

// In this case, the animation consists of changing myView's current frame to 
//endFrame over the course of 0.3 seconds. When the animation is complete, 
//myView is removed from the screen. 
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                     animations:^{ 
                         myView.frame = endFrame ;
                     }
                     completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             [myView removeFromSuperview];
                         }
                     }];
```

To get an idea of what you're doing, the view programming guide in the apple documentation is very useful, particularly the section on animations, [UIView animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).